# Angular modal return promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'd like to present the user with a popup warning modal before they perform an action (**delete** in this case). If they click `okay` in the modal, it'll proceed, if they click `cancel`, it'll do something else.

To do this, I'm trying to pass the modal promise along the chain back to the initial calling `$rootScope.openDirections('warning').then(...` so I can decide what to do there.

However I'm getting error:

**$rootScope.openDirections(...).then is not a function** `at Scope.$scope.deleteObj`

Telling me that the promise is not being returned:

```
    $scope.deleteObj = function (id, type) {
        $rootScope.openDirections('warning').then(function (res) {
            // Do Stuff
        }, function (err) {
            console.log('ERROR', err);
        });
```

This calls a $rootScope function: (I see that the object type here is a promise... so shouldn't it be able to return now to the original caller?)

```
    $rootScope.openDirections = function (type) {
        // A Promise: Object {result: Promise, opened: Promise, rendered: Promise}
        return Modal.showDirections(type);
    };
```

Which calls `Modal` factory to open directions modal:

```
     return {
            ...
            showDirections: function(type) {   
                return $modal.open({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                    controller: 'directionsCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        // Display custom modal template
                        obj: function () {
                            if (type === 'markdown') {
                                return {
                                    template: '/modals/directions.html'
                                };
                            } else {
                                return {
                                    template: '/modals/message.html'
                                };
                            }
                        },
                        testID : function () {
                            return 'WHAT DO I RETURN HERE?';
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Which renders `message.html` modal template:

```
<div class="admin-directions">
    <div class="directions">
        ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE THIS?
    </div>
    <p class="dismiss-admin-help" ng-click="okay()">Okay</p>
    <p class="dismiss-admin-help" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</p>
</div>
```

Which uses `directionsCtrl` for the Modal:

```
angular
    .module('DDE')
    .controller('directionsCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modalInstance', 'Modal', 'obj', 'Auth', 'VARS', '$route', '$location', 'testID',
        function ($rootScope, $scope, $modalInstance, Modal, obj, Auth, VARS, $route, $location, testID) {

            $scope.template = obj.template;

            $scope.testID = '';

            /**
             * Dismiss modal
             */
            $scope.ok = function() {
                $scope.testID = 'okay';
                return $modalInstance.result($scope.testID);
            };

            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $scope.testID = 'cancel';
                return $modalInstance.result($scope.testID);
            };

    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$modal.open returns a $modalInstance that has a property called result which is the promise. You have to call .then() on that. So in your case, you want this:

```
    $rootScope.openDirections('warning').result.then(function (res) {
        // Do Stuff
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('ERROR', err);
    });
```

Or alternatively, in your openDirections method, you could just return the promise:

```
      showDirections: function(type) {   
            return $modal.open({
               //all your current stuff stays the same here
             }).result; //<-- notice that you are now returning the promise
        }
```

Comment: Okay, my `$modal` instance is not within the same controller, but rather in its own factory. Therefore, what do I `resolve` exactly within the factory to pass back to the original caller?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Did your error go away when you did what I suggested?

Comment: The `$scope.ok` and `$scope.cancel` buttons no longer work on the modal

Comment: In your controller you should use $modalInstance.close() which will trigger the promise to be resolve. $modalInsance.dismiss() will cause it to be rejected. Whatever you pass into those methods will be the argument passed to the handlers you attach when you call .then().